# How can I make Xfce4 look like Ubuntu 10.04/10.10?

Tags: 10.04, 10.10, xfce, ambiance, radiance

I would like to install Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04)/Maverick Meerkat (10.10) but my computer only able to load Xfce4. I want to know if ambiance and radiance theme could be installed to my Xfce4 to make it look like Ubuntu 10.04/10.10 .

Ubuntu 10.04/10.10 look like this:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot from your question demonstrates GNOME 2.3x, not Xfce.

So you have to simply install [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/) (which is a fork of GNOME 2 using modern software components) as in [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

on any  Ubuntu LTS release like 18.04 LTS or 20.04 LTS and you will get needed look and feel.
Or do fresh install of Ubuntu MATE from its installation media.

Then switch panel layout to Traditional from MATE Tweak and enjoy:

> [image: Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS with Traditional Panel layout]

---

While using Xfce, which is installable by `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop^` you can get some similarity by launching Xfce4 Panel Profiles (by installation of `xfce4-panel-profiles` package and executing the command with same name afterwards) to select *GNOME 2* profile, but *System* item will be missed:

> [image: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Xfce4 using GNOME 2 panel profile]

Comment: Where can I get the GNOME 2 profile?

Comment: You can install full Xubuntu by `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop^` or install single package `xfce4-panel-profiles`. But my recommendation is still switching to MATE as a logical continuation of GNOME 2.